# Maximum single channel cv::Mat from multi channel cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using opencv through the C++ interface. I have a `cv::Mat m1` representing a multi channel image, from which I need to obtain a single channel image `m2` where a pixel has as value the maximum among all the values of the corresponding pixel in `m1` (a pixel in `m1` has multiple values, one for each channel). Does anybody know the most efficient way to obtain `m2` from `m1`?

Comment: have a look at http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20reduce%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20dim,%20int%20rtype,%20int%20dtype%29 but you would have to convert width*height 3-channel-elements in width*height*channel matrix first

Comment: How can I do the conversion, could you be more explicit? My be with Mat::reshape(), but in that case the matrix must satisfy Mat::IsCountinuous().

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this using `cv::reduce()` and `Mat::reshape()`. The key is to reshape `m1` into a single-channel image where each element of a row represents one color component. You can do this via `m1.reshape(1, m1.total())`. Then applying `reduce()` will give a `Mat` containing the maximum component value, and then it is a simple matter to reshape the result to give the shape of `m1`. A simple example follows:

```
uchar data[] = {1,2,3, 3,1,2, 2,1,3, 3,2,1};
cv::Mat m1(2,2, CV_8UC3, data); // Maximum component value is 3 for all pixels
cv::Mat m2;
cv::reduce(m1.reshape(1, m1.total()), m2, 1, CV_REDUCE_MAX);
m2 = m2.reshape(0, m1.cols); // 2x2 Mat, all elements are 3
```

Comment: I agree with your answer and I can apply it to my problem, but as I said before and according to OpenCV documentation m.reshape(x,y) can only be applied when m.IsContinuous() returns true. Any answer in that situation?

Comment: Write your own solution? It's not a hard of a problem to solve.